# How do I get the value of type input inside a table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<tbody id="TableBodyId">
  <tr>
    <td>First Value</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" value="Second Value"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to know how I can extract both the `first value` and the `second value` using either `JS` or `Jquery`. Previously, my table looked like this:

```
<tbody id="TableBodyId">
  <tr>
    <td>First Value</td>
    <td>Second Value</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And to get the values, I did this using `jQuery`:

```
var TableData = new Array();

$('#TableBodyId tr').each(function(row, tr)
{
    TableData[row] = {
        "firstValue" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
        "secondValue": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
    }
});
```

Then, I decided that I want to be able to change the values in the second cell, so I made it into:

```
<input type="text" size="5" value="Second Value"/>
```

The problem now, is that the `tableData` on second cell is `""` (in other words, blank). To solve this, I tried to do:

```
"firstValue": $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
"secondValue": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').val()
```

But no luck, Second Value still comes up as `""`. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You don't want the `.val()` of the `<td>`, you want the `.val()` of the `<input>`: `.find('td:eq(1) > input').val()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the value from the `<input>` element, like this:

```
TableData[row] = {
    "firstValue" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
    "secondValue": $(tr).find('td:eq(1) input').val()
}
```

## Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var TableData = [];

    $('#TableBodyId tr').each(function(row, tr)
    {
        TableData[row] = {
            "firstValue" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
            "secondValue": $(tr).find('td:eq(1) input').val()
        }
    });
    
    console.log(TableData);
});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody id="TableBodyId">
    <tr>
      <td>First Value</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="Second Value"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
"secondValue" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').val()
```

to

```
"secondValue" :$(tr).find('td input:eq(0)').val()
```